# Javascript inside HTML import not affecting imported HTML

Tags: javascript, firefox, html-imports

I am importing an html document, `form.html`, from a script located in my `index.html` file.

`form.html` is a basically a fragment of HTML and at the bottom of the html is an internal script that attaches the html to the main document:

Afterwards, I reference an external script that is supposed to do some stuff to the HTML in `form.html`. However, this fails to have an affect in Firefox.

If I inspect the `<head>` of the main document in Firefox developer tools, I can see the "document fragment" composed and with the correct scripting affect. However, the actual imported HTML that appears in the *body* is unaffected.

I have tried inlining the script at the bottom of `form.html`. I also tried using `window.onload` to attach the external script to the end of the `body` of the main document as well as trying to use a `link` tag as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047590/html-templates-and-html-import-inner-script-not-executing-in-firefox).

Not quite sure what else to try. I would like to keep the script modular and contained inside `form.html` if possible as to only request it when that HTML page is requested.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the [HTML Imports polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/html-imports), the processing of the imported document is only asynchronous. So you should wait for the `HTMLImportsLoaded` event or use the `HTMLImports.whenReady()` method to be sure the content was imported.

```
<head>
    <script src="html-imports.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" src="from.html">
<body>
    //code to be injected
    <script>
        document.addEventListener( 'HTMLImportsLoaded' , ev => {
            //you can safely access the imported code in the body
        } )
    </script>
```